# i am using specflow and i want to do automation test whereas it extract details from a file

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Do i need to write gherkin syntax for my details file? Any suggestions would be helpful

I already have a test running which does not loop through a file and has [bindings] and have written gherkin syntax which is running successfully

```
@userjourney
Scenario: Pick out presents
    Given that I have signed in to the saucedemo site
    When I select a random present
    And I click on the shopping cart
    Then I will be on the cart page
    When I click on the checkout button
    Then I will be on the checkout step one page
    When I fill in the first name <firstName>
    And I fill in the second name <secondName>
    And I fill in the city <city>
    And I click the continue button
    Then I will be on the checkout step two page
    When I click the finish button
    Then I will be on the checkout complete page 

Examples: 
    | firstName     | secondName | city       |
    | Brenda        | Maddox     | Birmingham |
```

Do i need to write gherkin syntax if abstracting data from a file to run the test?

But this is what i have done so far:

I have created a class called Nicespartans which is what the loop is abstracting from the details file. And passing those details called `selectRandomPresent()` method.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace AutomatedShopping.POMs
{
    public abstract class Nicespartan
    {
        public IWebDriver _seleniumDriver;
        
        public Nicespartan()
        {        
        }
        
        public virtual void SelectRandomPresent()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This the loop for the csv file

```
foreach (var line in santalist)
{
    var details = line.Split(',');
    
    if (bool.Parse(details[2]) &&
        bool.Parse(details[3]) && 
        bool.Parse(details[4]))
    {
        Nicespartan nicespartan1 = Nicespartan(details[0]);
        nicespartan1.SelectRandomPresent();  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow supports an [external data plugin](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/externaldata.html) which allows you to load examples for scenario outlines from a file. It supports CSV, XLSX and XLS file types are supported. Scenarios requiring data from an external file just need to be annotated with the `@DataSource` tag which specifies a relative path to the CSV file:

```
@userjourney
@DataSource:pickOutPresents.csv
Scenario: Pick out presents
    Given that I have signed in to the saucedemo site
    When I select a random present
    And I click on the shopping cart
    Then I will be on the cart page
    When I click on the checkout button
    Then I will be on the checkout step one page
    When I fill in the first name <firstName>
    And I fill in the second name <secondName>
    And I fill in the city <city>
    And I click the continue button
    Then I will be on the checkout step two page
    When I click the finish button
    Then I will be on the checkout complete page
```

The pickOutPresents.csv file would be located in the same folder as the feature file that loads it. The CSV file in your case would contain:

```
firstName,secondName,city
Joe,Sally,Chicago
...
```

CSV column headers need to match the `<xyz>` tokens in your scenario.